# bad reloc addr ess 0xc in section `.data'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to install "blist" python package in my system by using mingw32 compiler, but that is leading to the following error

```
c:\MinGW\bin/ld.exe: build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\blist\_blist.o: bad reloc addr
ess 0xc in section `.data'
```

I am trying to resolve it from last few hours, but still no use. Please help in resolving this issue.

I used this command "python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32"
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shwo the full build command and output please; it's probably a compiler/linker flag that's missing.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used `mingw32` to do native Python compiling, but I used `MSVC++2008` compiler without any problems. You can get the lite web installer from [here](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=7729279). This will download a small executable where you setup the program options and then will download the compiler from the Web for complete installation. Installing takes approx 250MiB of HDD.

Then try recompile your library (most of the time, I just do `easy_install library`, and if `library` has native components, it'll download, compile and install easily).

Hope I'd helped you!

PS: Not every version of MSVC can be used for every Python. I assumed you use Python 2.7.x (which I do) and that version should match 2008 edition. I don't know whether 3.x uses 2008, 2010, or newer. And BTW, you don't need the Visual Studio IDE, the Express Editions are just enough.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This one also giving error for me like "key error:u['path'] is not found" or else "\Microsoft was unexpected here"

Comment: Now I resolved this "\Microsoft was unexpected at this time" by removing  unexpected special characters in "PATH" environment variable. Refer to this link for problem description http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2524009 or http://www.blinnov.com/en/2010/06/04/microsoft-was-unexpected-at-this-time/